# OpenLaszlo 5.x - Deleting Imported Libraries

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx, laszlo

We have a very large app that is in OL vers 4.0.24 with many program options with in the app. It is such a large app that we load and unload libraries of code based on what option they take.

libHWT100.unload();   // unload the library, so that it can be reloaded 
libHWT100.load();   // reload the library so that we can instantiate them again

Fastforward to a new app we're creating with 5.x (nightly build info: Build: trunk@19533 (19533) Date: 2012-02-21T09:54:36Z) Following similar design approch since this is kind of our test for how our code once updated to the newer format will work as HTML5 version.

The library initially loads just like it use to, but now when I do the unload, I get the following error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'unload'. Obviously something has changed.

If I look at the docs. http://labs.openlaszlo.org/trunk-nightly/docs/developers/program-structure.html#d0e30050 #5, it still shows the unload() method.

Any one know how to unload an imported library now under 5.x? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this JIRA issue: http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-7676  André was one of the most active contributors at that time, he never got an answer to the question if deletion of imported libraries still works. I haven't tested that in the past three years.

Comment: Thanks raju (I always seem to forget to check the JIRA)... guess that basically lets me know that I'm not just doing something stupid. But I'm guessing I won't be knowing a true answer/work around any time soon.